# Downgrade AirPods firmware

Tags: bluetooth, airpods

I have a pair of gen 1 airpods which have stopped working since a certain firmware update. They will not receive any more updates as they are already deprecated.
The thing is that they are unusable now as they disconnect after barely a minute of listening. I have seen this problem happen to lots of people on the internet and there is no solution still, only buying the new ones.
Factory reset and pairing them again doesn't solve it.

What I wanted to try is to manually install a previous version of the firmware and I wanna know if it is possible to do it

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it’s not possible to manually install a specific version of the AirPods firmware. As @benwiggy as, you should take them into an Apple Store.

Those AirPods are still eligible for warranty (though unlikely) and out of warranty service.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201624