# Downgrading airpods pro 2

Tags: airpods, firmware, downgrade

I installed iOS 17 public beta, and I have a lot of bugs. I will downgrade to the iOS 16.6. During the usage of iOS 17 beta, I noticed that the AirPods Pro 2 also upgraded the firmware.

Do you know if I downgrade the iOS back to 16.6, if the AirPods will automatically reinstall the previous version since I will have iOS 16.6?

I want to know to see if it is worth going to the downgrade process, or not. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to downgrade the AirPods?

Comment: The new firmware came with new options like adaptive transparency, that previous version did not have. I can set this options in iOS 17. I'm not so sure that I will have the option to set them in iOS 16.6, or i might get some error in pairing or functionalities.

Comment: A device having a capability enabled by firmware doesn't mean it's going to fail if it connects to something that doesn't implement it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downgrade AirPods firmware](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440963/downgrade-airpods-firmware)

Comment: The new airpods firmware is going to expect to work with older OS as AirPods always need to support older devices that can’t upgrade. This seems like a hypothetical question. Can you edit it to clarify a specific issue you face?

Answer (score 2):

If you downgrade from iOS 16 to iOS 17, your phone will be fine but if you had Beta OS on your Apple Watch or AirPods, they won't work with iOS 16, and there is no way to downgrade those. I did the same mistake and now my watch and airpods do not work with iOS16. Have to wait until official release of iOS17.

Comment: I would expect that there is no firmware downgrade at all, almost ever for Apple. Caveat emptor when you load betas. You’ll need to accept instability and then wait for official fixes or new betas as Apple discloses this very clearly each year with the betas.